# Linear Differential Operator Property

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, derivatives, solution-verification

One of my exercises asks the following.

> Let $D\colon\mathbb R[X]\to\mathbb R[X]$ (where $\mathbb R[x]$ is the space of polynomials with real coeffients) be the differential operator $D(f(X))=f'(X)$. Show that $$e^{tD}(f(X))=f(X+t)$$for any real number $t$.

EDIT: Using mgn's suggestion in the comments, we write $$e^{tD}(f(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^nD^n(f(X))}{n!}=f(X)+tf'(X)+\frac{t^2f''(X)}2 +\frac{t^3 f^{(3)}(X)}{6}+\cdots.$$Now, we fix $X$ and find the Taylor series of the function $f(X+t)$ about $t=0$: $$f(X+t)=f(X)+tf'(X)+\frac{t^2f''(X)}{2}+\cdots.$$ But this is precisely $e^{tD}(f(X))$ and we are done.

Can somebody please verify that this proof is rigorous and correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By definition $e^{tD}= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{t^nD^n}{n!}$ so $e^{tD}(f(x)) = \sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{t^nD^n(f(x))}{n!}$, and $D^n(f(x)) = \underbrace{D \circ \cdots \circ D}_{n-\text{times}} (f(X))$. While $e^{tD(f(x))} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{t^n (D(f(x)))^n}{n!}$ so the meaning is different.

Comment: I edited my post above. Have I understood correctly what you said? Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understood my comment correctly and the proof which you presented seems correct to me. 
For more details you could write something like: let $X$ be fixed then $g(t):=f(X+t)$ is still a polynomial thus we may apply Taylor's expansion about a point $t=0$.
Thus 
$$f(X+t)=g(t) =  g(0) + \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!} t^n = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{f^{(n)}(X)}{n!} t^n =e^{tD}(f(X)),$$
where $f^{(0)} =f$.

Good job!